# Does Minecraft Dungeons crossplay work with local network?

Tags: minecraft-dungeons

Can I play a local network Minecraft Dungeons with crossplay?

With an Xbox and pc, or do I need Xbox live on the xbox and play online.

Answer (score 1):

No Minecraft Dungeons doesn’t have local network play like Minecraft, but up to 4 players can play on the same console